# Assigning a Color to each Point on the Plane

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

I have a dataset consisting of points on the plane and a corresponding color. These colors divide the plane into a few distinct regions. I would like to make a plot or diagram that nicely shows this breakdown into colored regions.

To generate some example data,

```
incircle[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{Red, x^2 + y^2 <= 25 }, {Blue, x^2 + y^2 > 25 }}];
data = Table[{i, j, incircle[i, j]}, {i, -10, 10, 1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}];
data = ArrayReshape[data, {441, 3}];

(*{{-10,-10,Blue},{-10,-9,Blue},{-10,-8,Blue},{-10,-7,Blue},...*)
```

This gives a list where each entry is a pair of x,y coordinates, and then red or blue depending on whether or not the coordinates are within a circle of radius five.

I can then make a list of coordinates and list of colors, and plot them accordingly using listplot:

```
pdat = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]}} & /@ data;
pcol = #[[3]] & /@ data;
ListPlot[pdat, PlotStyle -> pcol, PlotMarkers -> "\[FilledSquare]", ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image]

Which gives me a red circular region. Is there anyway to color each region according to the list more nicely and continuously, preserving a definite boundary between each region? My actual data is much more sporadic so the boundary between regions can be much more complex than a circle.

Comment: [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html)?

Comment: It looks like vertexcolors blend colors together between the different regions. Is there a way to preserve a definite boundary between each region?

Comment: if each is defined as a point, I don’t think this interpolation should happen. However, if you know certain regions will have certain colors, you might find a way to use a [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).

Comment: Hmmm yes maybe I could do something with colorfunction if I put all my data in a matrix and use arrayplot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Convex hull mesh

```
coords = CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}];
in = Select[Flatten[coords, 1], Norm@# <= 5 &];
out = Select[Flatten[coords, 1], Norm@# > 5 &];

p1 = Cases[Normal@ConvexHullMesh[out]["Graphics"], _Polygon, Infinity];
p2 = Cases[Normal@ConvexHullMesh[in]["Graphics"], _Polygon, Infinity];

Graphics[{
  ColorData[97, 1], First@p1,
  ColorData[97, 2], First@p2
  }]
```

[image: Output]

If anybody knows of a better way to turn a convex hull mesh into a polygon, please let me know.

## Interpolation

Interpolation with interpolation order 0.

```
data = Join[{#, 1} & /@ in, {#, 2} & /@ out];
interp = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0];

DensityPlot[
 interp[x, y],
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Using a higher interpolation order and rounding to get smoothed boundaries:

```
interp = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
DensityPlot[
 Round@interp[x, y],
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Concerning `ConvexHullMesh`:  I think `MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2]` yields a list of the 2-D polygons in the mesh.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would the mesh still work as well if I had multiple disconnected regions?

Comment: Interpolation seemed to work well for my data!

Comment: That's it, thanks @MichaelSeifert,

Comment: @Cheyne ok, good! I haven't looked into how `ConvexHullMesh` treats disconnected regions.

Answer (score 5):

## VoronoiMesh method

```
points = Drop[data, None, -1];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[points];
polygons = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
coloredpolygons = Map[{incircle @@ RegionCentroid[#], #} &, polygons];
Graphics[coloredpolygons]
```

[image]

`VoronoiMesh` automatically chooses the coordinates of the boundaries of the mesh, but you can also specify the boundaries via a second argument (`VoronoiMesh[points, {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]`) if you want.

This method generalizes nicely to irregularly located points as well.

```
points = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {200, 2}];
(* Remaining code as above *)
```

[image]

Note, however, that there is a bug in this code:  the centroid of a Voronoi cell is not necessarily its "base point".  This may make a difference in some cases, particularly if your base points are not uniformly distributed.

I will have to think if there's an easy way to color the Voronoi cells based on their base point, rather than their centroid.  Complicating matters is that `MeshPrimitives[VoronoiMesh[points]]` appears to shuffle the order of the resulting polygons (i.e., the $i$th polygon in the result does not necessarily contain the $i$th element of `points`.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit cleaner, and it does what you want:

```
pdat1=List/@data[[All,;;2]];
pcol1=List/@data[[All,3]];
ListPlot[pdat1, PlotStyle -> pcol1, PlotMarkers -> "\[FilledSquare]", ImageSize -> {250, 250}]
```

> `Same as original output from OP.`

This uses `VertexColors`, but is in `Graphics` using `Point`:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Medium],Point[data[[All,;;2]],VertexColors->data[[All,3]]]}, ImageSize -> {250, 250},Axes->True]
```

> [image: Image output of above code]

I’ll add other methods once I am back to a PC.

Comment: This looks the same as OP's image for me. What is the difference?

Comment: @C.E. the syntax looks cleaner and may be easier to understand. From what I gather, the OP is looking for a better syntax to color each point, while still keeping them points.

Comment: To the down-voter, what is the issue with this answer? Seemingly this is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think that OP may  be looking for something like what I posted in my answer. But let's wait and see.

Comment: @C.E. Ah this could be true. If that’s the case, I would update my answer. :)

Comment: @CATrevillian Yeah I was looking for something like in the other answer! I do appreciate the simpler syntax as well though!

Comment: @Cheyne I am trying to figure out how to apply a `DelaunayMesh` to achieve the same—I think it valuable to have to use only the `data` list that you have already defined. We shall see :)